# thymeleaf expression in title tag doesn't get evaluated

Tags: title, thymeleaf

I'm trying to have the title of my web page change based on whether the domain model is NEW or existing. The expression works everywhere else on the page but not in the <title></title>

Here's what I have:

```
<title th:text="${myobject['new']} ? 'Creating New' : 'Updating'">[Template Title]</title>
```

I have the same expression (copy and paste) in the page which renders fine:

```
<span th:text="${myobject['new']} ? 'Creating New' : 'Updating'">[Template Title]</span>
```

But it just doesn't work when in the title tag

I've also tried using th:if th:unless:

```
<title th:if="${myobject['new']}">Creating New</title>
<title th:unless="${myobject['new']}">Updating</title>
```

which I am also using later on in the page for showing different submit buttons. I just cant figure out why the title tag is behaving differently.

Also, I'm using ultraq layout which is part of the cause. The expression evaluates on a template that uses no layout template.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't have comparison before `?` sign. I managed to change title using this code:

**controller:**

```
@RequestMapping({"/site"})
    public String showSite(final ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("parameter", null);
        return "site";
    }
```

**html:**

```
<title th:text="${parameter != null} ? 'Parameter is null' : 'Its NOT null!'">this will be replaced anyway...</title>
```

So maybe try to compare `myobject['new']` to something (for ex. **null**).

HTH

Comment: I added code that I tested and got -1. Could you explain why?